# Missing shared libraries (g++ compile)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

Okay. So I've got simple app using GMP library. Here's the code:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int number=100;
    mpz_t a; mpz_init(a);
    mpz_t b; mpz_init(b);
    mpz_set_ui(b, 1);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    for (; number>0; number--)
    {
        cout<<b<<endl;
        mpz_add(b,b,a);
        mpz_sub(a,b,a);
    }
    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
}
```

I go for `g++ main.cpp -o app -lgmpxx -lgmp`. Compilation works, I mean no errors. Then I go for `./app` and here is what shows up:

[image]

Okay, but why? My `/usr/local/lib` looks like this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib main.cpp -o app -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

You could also add (as sudo) path to that library into /etc/ld.so.conf and then run (also as sudo) ldconfig, to rebuild cache. To see if your library was add correctly use this command:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libgmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Shared library access or dynamic linking is controlled by the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  So from a shell do `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the value will need to include `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: And if `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives me nothing? What can I do?

Comment: assuming bash `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` should do it.  You may want to save that in a script somewhere...

Comment: But where shall I put it?

Comment: Maybe the same place you are putting the executable that you created?  If you want it set every time you log in, then add a line to ~/.bashrc  However if you do have su privilege it is probably most elegant to use ldconfig as @j3s suggests